# JQuery Keyup on any form within a page?

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have a quick question about keyup with jquery. I have several form input fields on one page, they all have different id's but are all either one of two classes - numberbox or textbox and are all contained in a div id - content. Can I use these classes or the div to catch keypresses as I won't know the id of the form? Or even just catch the keypresses for all forms on the page. I don't know how well I explained that:

This will work with a form id= "add"

```
          $(add).keyup(function () {
             value = $(add).val()
             alphaCheck()
             ;
             }).keyup();
```

But if I don't know the form id only it's class or the div it is contained it can I use that? So something like:

```
 $(.class).keyup(function () {
```

or

```
 $(#div).keyup(function () {
```

I may have explained that really badly, but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. It would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you want:

```
$(".textbox, .numberbox").keyup(function ()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 $('form input:text').keyup(function(){
      alert('keyup');
 });
```

this will add keyup function on all input type text inside all forms.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":input").keyup(function(){alert("keyup");});
```

Will select all input form elements